# Entity Framework: delete record with its sub-records

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table with 3 columns: `ID, Name, ParentID.`

How can I delete a specific record with all its children (n levels deep)?

Using Entity Framework 3.5.

Comment: Ah, okay - you forgot to mention the tricky part: the table is **self-referencing** !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That the table is self referencing is application logic, it is not expressed in the SQL definition, and therefore is not understood by EF.

To delete these records through EF you need to write a routine that starts at the top and **loads** all the sub items. Then mark all these items as deleted, then call save changes.

To delete an item:

```
context.DeleteObject(item);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I know how to delete items
I asked what is: "mark all these items as deleted".
Should I add new column to flag for deletion?

Comment: No new column, what I meant is that DeleteObject marks the object as deleted, SaveChanges then does the actual deletion.

Comment: oh! ok. I plan to to load all items and then use recursion to mark the items that need to be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Set the database relationship to cascade delete and then rebuild your EDMX.

Comment: Cascade? But cascade works with multiple tables relationship,  I got only 1 table.

Answer (score 1):

@Shivesh - I suggest you to use a little method implemented with [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) to delete a son, and all of its parents. Thus, if a parent have parents you can delete them also, and so on.

An alternative could be implementing a stored procedure, the corresponding link in EntityFramework, and pretty do the same.

Hope that helps,

Comment: +1 probably easiest to wrap this up in a stored proc and just call it from EF.